# How to override Espresso IdleResource?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have an app that I would like to test with Espresso.

It has some button and after clicking on the buttons, there will be a countdown timer and animation showing the counting down.

I want to test when the animation is playing, clicking on other stuff but currently, Espresso will be blocked because the UI thread is never idle(there's a counting down animation!)

How do I override this to let all the other test steps continue?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I literally have no idea how to override this